# Can you get a job without running out of money?

Tags: succubox

Can you get a job without running out of money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

To unlock the option to be able to get a job, you will have to run out of money, so feel free to spend those last $40 on some loot boxes at the start of the game.